# Stop Timer In java Swing

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, mouselistener

I just started in Swing and using the `Timer`.  The program I wrote basically move a rectangle up and down to the specific point on the screen, I used the timer to get it run slowly and smoothly. But I got problem when trying to stop it. Here is the code below:

Lift class change y position of rectangle:

```
 public void moveUp(int destination){
        speed++;
        if(speed>5){
            speed = 5;
        }
        System.out.println("Speed is: "+speed);
        yPos -= speed;
        if(yPos < destination){
            yPos = destination;
            isStop = true;
        }
        setPos(xPos, yPos);
    }
```

And the class that got `Timer` and `MouseListener`:

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        liftArray.get(0).moveUp(rowDisctance / 2);
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with Timer#stop?

Comment: The class needs to keep a reference to the `Timer` created in the `mousePressed` method to do as advised by @MadProgrammer ..

Comment: You could check the state of the isStopped flag in the run method and stop the timer here, you can get the reference to the Timer from the ActionEvent source property

Comment: Post a [short runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to help you fix it. Also we have no idea what the stopping condition is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i did understood you correctly you are looking for something like this , you need two timers to control up and down mechanism , timer1 one moves down ,timer2 moves up or vice versa. You need to stop timer1 then inside timer1 you need to start timer2 , here is the code and animation below.

[image]

**add your fields**

```
  Point rv;
```

**set initial location to your dialog (rectangle) within constructor**

```
 rv= rectangle.this.getLocation();
```

**your button action performed**

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     timer1.setInitialDelay(0);
     timer1.start();
     jTextArea1.append("Timer 1 Started Moving Down\n");
}
```

**copy paste these two timer1 and timer2 like method in java**

```
    private Timer timer1 = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        rv.y++;



        if (rv.y == 500) {
            timer1.stop();
            jTextArea1.append("Timer 1 Stopped\n");
            jTextArea1.append("Timer 2 Started Moving Up\n");
            timer2.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer2.start();

        }

        rectangle.this.setLocation(rv.x , rv.y);
        rectangle.this.repaint();

    }
});



 private Timer timer2 = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       rv.y--;

        if (rv.y == 200 ) {
            timer2.stop();
            jTextArea1.append("Timer 2 Stopped\n");
        }
          rectangle.this.setLocation(rv.x , rv.y);
         rectangle.this.repaint();
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, you only need a single timer, with a delta value which dictates the direction of movement, this way, you won't end up with the possibility of both timers running at the same time

Answer (score 0):

To visualize how to proceed with this issue, I've coded a little example:

[image]

When you start it, two rectangles will be created. They start moving, when you click with the left mouse button on the drawing area.

Motion will stopped, when the destination line is arrived.

The logic depends on a **status in the Rectangle class**. When the timer event handler runs, every rectangle's **status is checked** and the timer is **stopped, if all rectangles reached have the isStopped status**:

```
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        /** 
                         * Variable isStopped is used to track, if any 
                         * rectangle didn't reach the destination yet
                         */
                        boolean isStopped = true;

                        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                            rectangles[i].moveUp(destination);
                            if (!rectangles[i].isStopped()) {
                                isStopped = false;
                            }
                        }
                        drawPanel.repaint();

                        /** 
                         * With all rectangles having arrived at destination, 
                         * the timer can be stopped
                         */
                        if (isStopped) {
                            timer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        }
```

Excerpt from the Rectangle class - here you see, how the isStopped status is handled - internally as private isStop variable - retrievable with the isStopped getter.

```
/** 
 * Moves the rectangle up until destination is reached
 * speed is the amount of a single movement.
 */
public void moveUp(int destination) {
    if (speed < 5) {
        speed++;
    }

    y -= speed;

    if (y < destination) {
        y = destination;
        isStop = true;
    }
}

public boolean isStopped() {
    return isStop;
}
```

**Here is the whole Program:**

**Main Program MovingRectangle**, creating the drawing area and providing control:

```
package question;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MovingRectangle extends JPanel {
    /**
     * The serial version uid.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[10];
    private int count;
    private int destination;

    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private DrawingPanel drawPanel;
    private JButton stop;

    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangles");
                frame.setContentPane(new MovingRectangle());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public MovingRectangle(){
        /** Imaginary horizontal line - the destination */
        destination = 200;

        /** Create the control panel for the left side containing the buttons */
        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 400));

        /** Create the button */
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        controlPanel.add(stop);

        /** Create a hint how to start the movement. */
        JTextArea textHint = new JTextArea(5, 10);
        textHint.setEditable(true);
        textHint.setText("Please click on the drawing area to start the movement");
        textHint.setLineWrap(true);
        textHint.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        controlPanel.add(textHint);

        /** Add control panel to the main panel */
        add(controlPanel);

        /** Create the drawing area for the right side */
        drawPanel = new DrawingPanel();

        /** Add the drawing panel to the main panel */
        add(drawPanel);

        /** With a left mouse button click the timer can be started */
        drawPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            /** 
                             * Variable isStopped is used to track, if any 
                             * rectangle didn't reach the destination yet
                             */
                            boolean isStopped = true;

                            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                                rectangles[i].moveUp(destination);
                                if (!rectangles[i].isStopped()) {
                                    isStopped = false;
                                }
                            }
                            drawPanel.repaint();

                            /** 
                             * With all rectangles having arrived at destination, 
                             * the timer can be stopped
                             */
                            if (isStopped) {
                                timer.stop();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    timer.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        /** Add two rectangles to the drawing area */
        addRectangle(100, 30, 0, 370, new Color(255, 0, 0));
        addRectangle(120, 50, 200, 350, new Color(0, 0, 255));
    }

    private void addRectangle(final int widthParam, final int heightParam, final int xBegin, final int yBegin, final Color color) {
        /** Add a new rectangle, if array not filled yet */
        if (count < rectangles.length) {
            rectangles[count] = new Rectangle(widthParam, heightParam, xBegin, yBegin, color);
            count++;
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

    /** This inner class is used to handle the button event. */
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == stop){
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    /** This inner class provides the drawing panel */
    private class DrawingPanel extends JPanel{
       /** The serial version uid. */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            setBackground(new Color(200, 220, 255));
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);

            /** Draw destination line */
            g.setColor(new Color(150, 150, 150));
            g.drawLine(0, destination, 400, destination);

            /** Draw rectangles */
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                rectangles[i].display(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **Rectangle Class** for the moving shape:

```
package question;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Rectangle {
    private int x, y, width, height;
    private Color color;
    private boolean isStop = false;
    private int speed = 0;

    public Rectangle(final int widthParam, final int heightParam, final int xBegin, final int yBegin, final Color colorParam) {
        width = widthParam;
        height = heightParam;
        this.x = xBegin;
        this.y = yBegin;
        this.color = colorParam; 
    }

    public void display(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(this.color);
        g.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }  

    /** 
     * Moves the rectangle up until destination is reached
     * speed is the amount of a single movement.
     */
    public void moveUp(int destination) {
        if (speed < 5) {
            speed++;
        }

        y -= speed;

        if (y < destination) {
            y = destination;
            isStop = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isStopped() {
        return isStop;
    }
}
```